# CGAffineTransform messing up ViewFrame

Tags: swift, core-animation, uiviewanimation, cgaffinetransform, uiviewanimationtransition

I have an `UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning` where one of the animations is an scale using `CGAffineTransform`

```swift
toView.frame.origin.y = containerView.frame.size.height - toView.frame.height
fromView.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.96, y: 0.94)
fromView.frame = fromView.frame.offsetBy(dx: 0, dy: self.topOffset)
```

This get my frame from `(0.0, 0.0, 375.0, 667.0)` to `(7.5, 20.00999999999999, 360.0, 626.98)`, and on the way back:

```swift
toView.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
toView.frame = toView.frame.offsetBy(dx: 0, dy: -self.topOffset)
fromView.frame.origin.y = containerView.frame.size.height
```

The problem is: instead of the frame come back to the original, it messes up and now I get: `0.0, -5.684341886080802e-14, 375.0, 667.0000000000001)`, the main problem of course is the y positioning.

Mind that the value self.topOffset is 0, and I've tried to remove this line, without any result.

And the `fromView` from the first snippet is the `toView` from the second.

If you want to check the full code of that function:

```swift
func animateTransition(using transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning) {
        guard let fromViewController = transitionContext.viewController(forKey: .from),
            let toViewController = transitionContext.viewController(forKey: .to),
            let toView = toViewController.view,
            let fromView = fromViewController.view,
            let containerView = containerView else { return }


        let isPresenting = fromViewController == presentingViewController
        if isPresenting {
            toView.frame.origin.y = fromView.frame.size.height
        }

        UIView.animate(withDuration: transitionDuration(using: transitionContext),
                       delay: 0,
                       usingSpringWithDamping: 1,
                       initialSpringVelocity: 0,
                       options: .curveEaseInOut,
                       animations: {
            if isPresenting {
                toView.frame.origin.y = containerView.frame.size.height - toView.frame.height
                fromView.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.96, y: 0.94)
                fromView.frame = fromView.frame.offsetBy(dx: 0, dy: self.topOffset)
            }
            else {
                toView.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
                toView.frame = toView.frame.offsetBy(dx: 0, dy: -self.topOffset)
                fromView.frame.origin.y = containerView.frame.size.height
            }
        }) { (finished) in
            if finished {
                transitionContext.completeTransition(!transitionContext.transitionWasCancelled)
            }
        }
    }
```

---

By the way, keeping the initial value on a variable and setting it after, solves the problem, but this seems like a workaround not a solution. I want to understand why it is happening and if there's a better way to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is what I think might be wrong. From [Docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622621-frame) on UIView frame,

> If the transform property is not the identity transform, the value of
>   this property is undefined and therefore should be ignored.

you should not use frame property after setting transform. Instead as stated in doc,

> Changes to this property can be animated. However, if the transform
>   property contains a non-identity transform, the value of the frame
>   property is undefined and should not be modified. In that case,
>   reposition the view using the center property and adjust the size
>   using the bounds property instead.

So

```
fromView.frame = fromView.frame.offsetBy(dx: 0, dy: self.topOffset)
```

need to be modified as

```
fromView.center = fromView.frame.center + self.topOffset
fromView.frame = fromView.frame.bounds
```

But I don't think we need to modify toView code because we are setting transform to Identity before setting the frame.

---

Based on what is said above what solves the problem is modifying the first block from:

```
toView.frame.origin.y = containerView.frame.size.height - toView.frame.height
fromView.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.96, y: 0.94)
fromView.frame = fromView.frame.offsetBy(dx: 0, dy: self.topOffset)
```

To

```
toView.frame.origin.y = containerView.frame.size.height - toView.frame.height
fromView.frame = fromView.frame.offsetBy(dx: 0, dy: self.topOffset)
fromView.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.96, y: 0.94)
```

Basically doing the frame reposition BEFORE applying the transform.

Comment: So basically what you're saying is that I cannot modify the frame AFTER I apply any kind of transform, by this theory I did a test and inverted the first block third line with the second and worked like a charm. Thanks!!!
By the way, I'll edit your answer with what I've done.